# remote connection

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2012

Im trying to connect to a remote sql server using windows authenication. I'm using visual studio 2012 and going to a remote sql server 2012. I have already checked in sql studio that it is set up for both sql authentication and windows authentication.  I'm getting an error message Login failed for user ad\dkboon01

Comment: are you able to connect SQL server using SSMS? Also try running visual studio "run as admin".

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Remote Connection to the server.  
On 2008 (I assume 2012 is similar location) 
Connect to Mgt Studio on local machine, right click on server & choose properties. 
Connection Tab 
Tick "Allow remote connection to this server" 
Restart SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Windows User `ad\dkboon01` is added as a login in SQL Server?  Just because you are able to use Windows Authentication doesn't necessarily mean that particular user has access.  It has to be added as a principle, or be part of a Group that is a principle.  Access is explicit.